# Fitting the image in the cell

Tags: html, css, image

How do I fit the image in the cell?
I want to fit the entire image in the yellow part
[image]

Below is my code.

```
<!--Top Part-->
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
<div style="display: table-row">
<div style="width: 770px; height:270px; display: table-cell; background-color:#B2BABB;">
<p style="font-family: Allerta Stencil; font-size:40px; color:red; padding-top: 65; 
padding-left:120;">SCOPE<br>Industries Berhad<br>
<span style="font-size:25px; color:black; font-family: Allan;">
A simple solution,<br></span>
<span style="font-size:25px; color:black; font-family: Allan; padding-left: 135;">
for a complex problem.</span></p>
</div>

<!-- Slideshow -->  
<div style="display: table-cell; background-color:#F7DC6F ">
<img src="123.jpg" style="width:200;">
</div>
<!-- Slideshow End -->
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting the width in CSS you must specify a unit. So instead of `width: 200` you need to use `width: 200px`. The `px` stands for pixel.

Alternatively, you can try setting the image width to `100%`.

Comment: I added the px but now that part is going over the footer part

Comment: @NgWeiShen If the picture is going beyond the container boundaries is because the image and the container have different aspect ratios. You can try setting the image `height` but that might skew the image. If you want to clip the image at the bottom you can set the container `overflow: hidden`. Another way to tackle this is either make the container narrower or taller until it matches the image aspect ratio

Comment: Ah ok, I found out the problem. I put the footer inside the body. But right now everytime I enlarge the image, the table will become bigger

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed your wrapper(root) element width then try to use `width:100%` for inside element like- for image tag so that i could adjust as per your devices width.

```
<img src="123.jpg" style="width:100%;">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set this image is background of the div, and use "background-size: cover;"